# how to create users ,groups in ubuntu 14.4

Tags: ubuntu

I am new to ubuntu. I have installed ubuntu 14.4.
I want to execute programs on it.
please tell me where will i get 100% help for learning ubuntu from very beginning.
is it possible to create users and groups and set permissions and ownership in ubuntu which is not in LAN?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to read books. There are several books out there that will come in commercial form or for free that you can find simply by searching the web.
These two links give you some info:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1874/are-there-any-good-books-for-new-ubuntu-user
https://askubuntu.com/questions/575/list-of-free-ubuntu-books
and the official book is this: [http://www.amazon.com/The-Official-Ubuntu-Book-Edition/dp/0133017605](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0133017605)

also if you faced any problems or you had any questions you can go to askubuntu.com and ask for help.
For user and groups this web page can help you [Enter HERE](https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/linux-users-and-groups).